# How to rotate the arc with in the Circle1 path continuously?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

[image]

I am designing the web pages for that I have to rotate the arc in the circle path. I don't have previous experience in javafx. How do I rotate the Arc in the circle?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="666.0" prefWidth="645.0">
         <children>
            <Circle fx:id="circcle2" fill="#f700001d" layoutX="323.0" layoutY="298.0" radius="50.0" stroke="#f50000" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="2.0" />
            <Circle fx:id="circle1" fill="#f110000d" layoutX="323.0" layoutY="298.0" radius="70.0" stroke="#ea0202" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="2.0" />
            <Arc fx:id="arc" fill="#ff252100" layoutX="314.0" layoutY="284.0" length="70.0" radiusX="50.0" radiusY="50.0" startAngle="96.0" stroke="#f20000" strokeLineCap="BUTT" strokeWidth="10.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a controller. In the controller you need to animate the `startAngle` property of the `Arc` using a `Timeline`.

**Note:** I recommend using `centerX` and `centerY` instead of the layout properties. Furthermore wrapping a `AnchorPane` inside another currently isn't necessary, even more so since you're not using any anchors. A simple `Pane` would do the trick.

```xml
<Pane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="mypackage.Controller"
      prefHeight="666.0" prefWidth="645.0">
   <children>
       <Circle fx:id="circcle2" fill="#f700001d" centerX="323.0" centerY="298.0" radius="50.0" stroke="#f50000" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="2.0" />
       <Circle fx:id="circle1" fill="#f110000d" centerX="323.0" centerY="298.0" radius="70.0" stroke="#ea0202" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="2.0" />
       <Arc fx:id="arc" fill="#ff252100" centerX="323.0" centerY="298.0" length="70.0" radiusX="63.0" radiusY="63.0" startAngle="96.0" stroke="#f20000" strokeLineCap="BUTT" strokeWidth="10.0" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

The arc radius is calculated as `outerRadius - strokeWidth/2 = (circle1.radius - circle1.strokeWidth) - arc.strokeWidth / 2`, i.e. in this case `(70 - 2) - 10/2 = 63`.

```
package mypackage;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Arc arc;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        Timeline animation = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(arc.startAngleProperty(), arc.getStartAngle(), Interpolator.LINEAR)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(arc.startAngleProperty(), arc.getStartAngle() - 360, Interpolator.LINEAR))
        );
        animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        animation.play();
    }

}
```

For counter-clockwise animation add `360` instead of subtracting it for the `KeyValue` of the second `KeyFrame`.

Comment: animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        animation.play();  In these two lines i get an error. where I need to import the animation statement.

Comment: In the above code what is animation?, I'm getting error there, is it object of animation class or any thing else. I have tried to create object for animation class.But I can't..please help me.

Comment: @venkataramireddypulikhandam add `import javafx.animation.Animation` or use the fully qualified name (`javafx.animation.Animation.INDEFINITE`). This is the constant the expression is supposed to refer to: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#INDEFINITE

Comment: sorry sir,My problem is not solved.we need to install any external jars...?

Comment: It shows like this.........The import javafx.animation.Animation.INDEFINITE cannot be resolved

Comment: The arc radius is calculated as outerRadius - strokeWidth/2 = (circle1.radius - circle1.strokeWidth) - arc.strokeWidth / 2, i.e. in this case (70 - 2) - 10/2 = 63.I didn't understand this.

Comment: @venkataramireddypulikhandam You need to import the class containing the constant, if you're refering to it via `ClassName.CONSTANT_NAME` like in this code, i.e. remove `.INDEFINITE` from the end of the import. If you don't want an import or theres a naming confilict with some other `Animation` class, you could also use `animation.setCycleCount(javafx.animation.Animation.INDEFINITE);`.

Comment: The calculation of the radius is based on the following facts: You need to use `StrokeType.CENTERED` (the default) to get the look right. This stroke type means that the radius property specifies where the center of the stroke is positioned the line extends and half of the stroke width inwards and outwards. Your outer circle has stroke type `INSIDE` and a stroke width of 2 which means the inner stroke radius is 68. You've chosen stroke width 10 for the arc and want to align the outer radius of the arc with the circle, so you need to subtract half the stroke width to get the radius.